# How to get scroll directions to hide my bottombar

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm implementing a scroll behaviour that when the user scrolls away from index 0 I show a scroll to top action, also I hide the bottombar to let the user have more visibility of the list.

Now, this is working fine if I scroll after the first visible index and when I come back to the first visible index I get my bottombar shown and my scroll to top button hidden

### Example

[image]

What I want to do is that when I scroll away from index 0 I show my scroll to top button and hidde my bottom bar, but then if I scroll up a little bit I want to hide the scroll to top button and show again the bottom bar

This is my architecture and my composables setup

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            CryptoTheme {
                val navController = rememberNavController()
                val bottomBarState = rememberSaveable { (mutableStateOf(true)) }
                Scaffold(
                    bottomBar = {
                        BottomBarNavigation(
                            navController = navController,
                            bottomBarState = bottomBarState.value
                        )
                    }
                ) { innerPadding ->
                    Box(modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)) {
                        NavigationGraph(
                            navController = navController,
                            onBottomNavStateChange = {
                                bottomBarState.value = it
                            })
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun NavigationGraph(
    navController: NavHostController,
    onBottomNavStateChange: (Boolean) -> Unit
) {
    NavHost(navController, startDestination = BottomNavItem.HomeScreen.screen_route) {
        composable(BottomNavItem.HomeScreen.screen_route) {
            HomeScreen(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize(),
                onBottomNavStateChange = onBottomNavStateChange
            )
        }
    }

    @OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
    @Composable
    fun HomeScreen(
        modifier: Modifier,
        onBottomNavStateChange: (Boolean) -> Unit
    ) {

        val listState = rememberLazyListState()
        val showScrollToTopButton by remember {
            derivedStateOf {
                listState.firstVisibleItemIndex > 0
            }
        }
        val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

        LazyColumn(
            modifier = modifier,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            state = listState
        ) {

            item { }
            item { }
            items(mylist) { ... }
        }
        AnimatedVisibility(visible = showScrollToTopButton, enter = fadeIn(), exit = fadeOut()) {
            onBottomNavStateChange.invoke(!showScrollToTopButton)
            GoToTop {
                scope.launch {
                    listState.scrollToItem(0)
                }
            }
        }
    }

@Composable
fun GoToTop(goToTop: () -> Unit) {
    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        FloatingActionButton(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(16.dp)
                .size(50.dp)
                .align(Alignment.BottomEnd),
            onClick = goToTop,
            backgroundColor = Color.White, contentColor = Color.Black
        ) {
            Icon(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_baseline_arrow_upward_24),
                contentDescription = "go to top"
            )
        }
    }
}
```

The only thing I do is propagate the state to hide/show the bottom bar, but that is attached also to the same logic as showing/hiding the scroll to top button, which will trigger after index is greater than 0 in the list

I think a solution could be to listen to when the user is going down or up into the list, but ListState does not provide that to me

I did it this way in order to just use this functionality inside my home screen and not in every place in the app where I have a list

My bottombar navigation only hides or show the bottom bar

```
@Composable
fun BottomBarNavigation(navController: NavController, bottomBarState: Boolean) {
    val items = listOf(
        BottomNavItem.HomeScreen,
        BottomNavItem.FiatToCryptoScreen,
        BottomNavItem.SimpleSwapScreen,
        BottomNavItem.ExchangeArbitrageScreen,
        BottomNavItem.ProfileScreen
    )
    AnimatedVisibility(visible = bottomBarState,
        enter = slideInVertically(initialOffsetY = { it }),
        exit = slideOutVertically(targetOffsetY = { it })) {
        BottomNavigation(
            backgroundColor = colorResource(id = R.color.black),
            contentColor = Color.White
        ) { ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I added a way to listen to scrolling in the lazylist

```
@Composable
private fun LazyListState.isScrollingUp(): Boolean {
    var previousIndex by remember(this) { mutableStateOf(firstVisibleItemIndex) }
    var previousScrollOffset by remember(this) { mutableStateOf(firstVisibleItemScrollOffset) }
    return remember(this) {
        derivedStateOf {
            if (previousIndex != firstVisibleItemIndex) {
                previousIndex > firstVisibleItemIndex
            } else {
                previousScrollOffset >= firstVisibleItemScrollOffset
            }.also {
                previousIndex = firstVisibleItemIndex
                previousScrollOffset = firstVisibleItemScrollOffset
            }
        }
    }.value
}
```

And then just used it in

```
AnimatedVisibility(visible = !listState.isScrollingUp(), enter = fadeIn(), exit = fadeOut()) {
                onBottomNavStateChange.invoke(listState.isScrollingUp())
                GoToTop {
                    scope.launch {
                        listState.scrollToItem(0)
                    }
                }
            }
```

[image]